# How to subtract table2 from table1 in mysq?

Tags: mysql, subtraction

I am looking for an easy way to subtract values existing in a table, out of another table. Some kind of "minus" operator for MySQl

http://www.techonthenet.com/sql/minus.php

Deleting them through code, (looping through the first table, deleting rows matching the second) would be my last option, as I have simplified my problem, but it is far more complex.

**Note that complexity lies in the repeating rows. There are no unique fields, and every repeated row must be preserved.**

**EXAMPLE:**

Given a table with letters (in any given order), A is written 5 times, B 3 times:

```
Table1
+--+
|ID|
+--+
|A | 
|A | 
|A | 
|B | 
|A | 
|B |
|B | 
|A | 
+--+
```

And another table with same letters, A occurs 2 times, B occurs once.

```
Table2
+--+
|ID|
+--+
|A | 
|A | 
|B | 
+--+
```

**The desired output would be:**

```
+--+
|ID|
+--+
|A | 
|A | 
|A | 
|B | 
|B | 
+--+
```

A occurs 5 times in the first table, and 2 times in the second, that means 3 rows in the output.
B occurs 3 times in the first table, and 1 in the second, thus, result would be 2 rows.

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

You might try this :

```
select id from (
    select id,concat(id,
    case when id = @id then @rownum := @rownum+1 else @rownum:=1 end) as x,
    @id:=id
    from table1 inner join(select @rownum :=1,@id:='') n
) as t where x not in(
select x from(
    select concat(id,
    case when id = @id then @rownum := @rownum+1 else @rownum:=1 end) as x,
    @id:=id
    from table2 inner join(select @rownum :=1,@id:='') n2
) t2)
```

We need to make the column unique with rownumbers. and since mysql doesn't support rownum as oracle, we need variable (@rownum,@id) to generate rownumber. And then table1 should be looks like this: `A1,A2,A3` and table2 too. so we can get result with query something like `where id not in(id in table2`.

Answer (score 0):

The following query will give you the output needed. Here, we count the number of `Id`s and during selection from `table1`, maintain a count to show only `counted` number of items from `table2`:

```
SELECT 
    id
FROM
    (SELECT 
        *,
            IF(@prevvalue <> id, @counter:=0, @counter),
            IF(@counter < counter, @counter:=@counter + 1, NULL) shouldshow,
            @prevvalue:=id
    FROM
        (SELECT 
        table1.*, table2.id t2id, table2.counter
    FROM
        table1
    JOIN (SELECT 
        COUNT(id) counter, id
    FROM
        table2
    GROUP BY id) table2 ON (table1.id = table2.id)
    ORDER BY table1.id) table1, (SELECT @counter:=0, @prevvalue:=NULL) countertable) table1
WHERE
    shouldshow IS NULL
ORDER BY id;
```